# Check with batch if the process is answering or not

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

```
:loop
>nul timeout /t 600 /nobreak
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -c "Get-Process -Name programm | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Responding -eq $false}"
if not errorlevel 1 goto loop
```

This is not working, I think the errorlevel is the problem, but I cant solve it.
I want to check if the process is answering or not. If not I want to check the process again after a timeout.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Errorlevel and Exit codes](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html):

> Almost all applications and utilities will set an *Exit Code* when
>   they complete/terminate. The exit codes that are set do vary, in
>   general a code of `0` (false) will indicate *successful completion*.
>   
> …
>  When an external command is run by `CMD.EXE`, it will detect
>   the executable's *Return* or *Exit Code* and set the `ERRORLEVEL` to
>   match. In most cases the `ERRORLEVEL` will be the same as the *Exit
>   code*, but there are some cases where they can differ.

It's *Exit Code* for `PowerShell` as shown in the following examples:

- **Unsuccessful completion** ( `errorlevel` 1 ):

```
==> powershell -noprofile -c "Get-Process -Name invalid_programm"
Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "invalid_programm". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Process -Name invalid_programm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (invalid_programm:String) [Get-Process],ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

==> echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
errorlevel=1
```

- **Successful completion** ( `errorlevel` 0 )

```
==> powershell -noprofile -c "return 1"
1

==> echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
errorlevel=0
```

- **Successful completion** ( `errorlevel` set explicitly using the [`exit` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-5.1#exit))

```
==> powershell -noprofile -c "exit 2"

==> echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
errorlevel=2
```

Hence, you could use the following code snippet (which should always successfully complete):

```
try { 
    $x = @(Get-Process -Name programm -ErrorAction Stop | 
             Where-Object -FilterScript {-not $_.Responding})
    exit $x.Count
} catch { 
    exit 5000          # or other `absurd` value
}
```

Rewriting the above as an one-liner (using aliases), you could meet following scenarios:

1. A process with specified name **not found**

```
==> powershell -noprofile -c "try{$x=@(gps programm -EA Stop|? {-not $_.Responding});exit $x.Count} catch {exit 5000}"

==> echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
errorlevel=5000
```

2. A process with specified name **found & responding**

```
==> powershell -noprofile -c "try{$x=@(gps cmd -EA Stop|? {-not $_.Responding});exit $x.Count} catch {exit 5000}"

==> echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
errorlevel=0
```

3. One process with specified name **found & NOT responding**

```
==> powershell -noprofile -c "try{$x=@(gps HxOutlook -EA Stop|? {-not $_.Responding});exit $x.Count} catch {exit 5000}"

==> echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
errorlevel=1
```

4. More processes with specified name **found & NOT responding**

```
==> powershell -noprofile -c "try{$x=@(gps -EA Stop|? {-not $_.Responding});exit $x.Count} catch {exit 5000}"

==> echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
errorlevel=4
```

Please note incompleteness of above enumeration: we *could imagine* scenario where run more processes with specified name, some of them responding while other not-responding. 
(In other words, *found & NOT responding* **does not imply** that there does not exist another *found & responding* of the same name…)